# How to add a number to the middle of a string in a time-efficient way?

Tags: c, string, performance, strcat

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    const char* pFilename = NULL;

    pFilename = "Something.png"

    functionX(pFilename, argX);
}
```

But then, I'd like to call that function inside a loop, with different filenames like "Something0.png", "Something1.png", etc

After a bit of digging, I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    const char* pFilename = NULL;
    char buffer[4];
    char nameStd[] = "Something";
    char namePng[] = ".png";
    char nameAll[17];

    pFilename = "Something.png"

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", i);
        strcat(nameAll, pFilename);
        strcat(nameAll, buffer);
        strcat(nameAll, namePng);
        functionX(nameAll, argX);
        memset(nameAll,0,strlen(nameAll));
    }
}
```

Well, I'm not sure this will work. And I cannot execute the code at the moment (as `functionX` needs specific peripherals).
But even if it does work, is it really the most time-efficient way to do this?

Comment: maybe fastest would be to have a string "Something___.png" and sprintf the number right into where the _ are (either with %03d, or with "%d.png" if you don't want trailing zeros), then you don't need to do stringcopies at all

Comment: `char nameAll[17];` Why scrimp? `char nameAll[ 32 ]; sprintf( nameAll, "Prefix%d.png", i );` One statement... And, don't reset the buffer afterward. Unnecessary... Make code that works and don't worry about performance... Computers aren't made from vacuum tubes anymore...

Comment: A bit off topic, but `char nameAll[17];  strcat(nameAll, pFilename);` is undefined behaviour because nameAll[] hasn't been cleared (ie isn't a valid string that you can strcat to). Use `strcpy` the first time, or just `nameAll[0] = '\0'`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I used 17 as string size just.. because. No particular reason. I wasn't sure I could do that with `sprintf`, everywhere people were recommending `snprintf` instead. Maybe in different scenarios and I misunderstood

Comment: The value 17 makes a reader ask, "Is that right? Big enough?" Using 32 or 100 or 128 shouldn't affect your program unless it's _really_ squeezed for stack (few are these days.) If the data is obviously not going to overflow an ample-sized buffer, `sprintf()` should be fine. Yes, use `snprintf()` when dealing with less predictable data...

Comment: time-efficiency? That should not be a real problem, generating 100 filenames, whatever, the method used, will not consume significant amount of time. The simplest is to use something like `sprintf(nameAll,"Something%d.png",'i);`

Comment: @ATSlooking4things You can forget about `sprintf` completely, because `snprintf` can do everything it can, and more. `sprintf` has outdated API design, but people still use it because it is still present in lot of outdated learning resources, including some advice on this site.

Comment: @user694733 so you're telling me I should do `snprintf(nameAll, sizeof(nameAll), "Something%d.png", i);` instead of `sprintf(nameAll, "Something%d.png",i)` ?

Comment: You only need to update the number + suffix part of the string.

Comment: @ATSlooking4things Yes.

Comment: @ATSlooking4things: definitely prefer `snprintf` over `sprintf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually much easier to assemble parts.  Either via snprintf() as  suggested above, or by building the string yourself.  The prefix doesn't change and you only need to add the suffix when another digit is added.  It's about 60% faster than `snprintf()` for 1e6 strings but probably not worth the complexity:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// A constant expression of log10(INT_MAX) + 1
#define str_uint32_t_len sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT * 21306 / 70777 + 2

uint32_t uint32_t_len(uint32_t i) {
    uint32_t n = !i;
    for(uint32_t j = i; j; j /= 10, n++);
    return n;
}

// s is not '\0' terminated
char *uint32_t_to_str(uint32_t u, size_t u_len, char *s) {
    for(char *p = s + u_len; s <= --p; u /= 10)
        *p = '0' + u % 10;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char prefix[] = "Something";
    char suffix[] = ".png";

    // builds the path template "Something\0.png"
    char path[sizeof prefix + str_uint32_t_len + sizeof suffix - 2] = {0};
    strcpy(path, prefix);
    strcpy(path + sizeof prefix, suffix);

    size_t u_len[] = {1, 1};
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        u_len[1] = uint32_t_len(i);
        uint32_t_to_str(i, u_len[1], path + sizeof prefix - 1);
        if(u_len[0] < u_len[1]) {
            u_len[0] = u_len[1];
            strcpy(path + sizeof prefix + u_len[1] - 1, suffix);
        }
        printf("%s\n", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: To shave off a few more cycles, you could investigate computing partial updates of the converted string of digits: 90% of conversions involve only changing the last digit and no update of the suffix required.  You could also increment the digit string directly, which would remove all divisions.

Comment: `fwrite_unlocked()` is significantly faster than `printf()` but not what we are optimizing.

Comment: @chqrlie I had the most of the code laying around anyways from some logging code I wrote, and "for fun" was the only reason why I wrote up my answer to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in assembling parts for performance reasons on such cases: composing the filename with `snprintf` is simple and efficient and far less expensive than `fopen()` anyway.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int functionX(const char *filename, ...) {
    //printf("%s\n", filename);
}

int main(void) {
    int argX = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        char filename[32];
        snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Something%d.png", i);
        functionX(filename, argX);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is the recommended approach, fast enough for most purposes.  The rest of the answer is for educational purposes only.

---

If you absolutely want to squeeze the overhead, you could try and update the string directly:

Here is an example with a benchmark:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void functionX(const char *filename, ...) {
    //printf("%s\n", filename);
}

int s_update(char *s, int len) {
    for (char *p = s + len - 1;;) {
        if (++*p <= '9')
            return len;
        *p = '0';
        if (p == s) {
            memmove(s + 1, s, strlen(s) + 1);
            *s = '1';
            return len + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char filename[32];
    int argX = 1;
    int repeat = 1000000;
    clock_t c0 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "Something%d.png", i);
        functionX(filename, argX);
    }
    clock_t c1 = clock();
    strcpy(filename, "Something0.png");
    char *p = strchr(filename, '0');
    int len = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
        functionX(filename, argX);
        len = s_update(p, len);
    }
    clock_t c2 = clock();

    printf("snprintf: %.3fms\n", (c1 - c0) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("s_update: %.3fms\n", (c2 - c1) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
snprintf: 81.443ms
s_update: 3.085ms
```

Beware that this notable performance improvement (**27x** faster) does not justify such clever code in most cases: for your example (100 iterations), the difference is only 30 **microseconds**, 0,00003 seconds, barely measurable.

Comment: Bigger difference than I expected (on my machine):
snprintf: 62.290ms
s_update: 4.695ms
uint32_t_to_str: 28.212ms
Good job!  I thought your solution was interesting.

Comment: "only" 30ms might help or not. Not sure yet, but I'm working with somewhat constrained requirements. The `function()` itself is taking up a lot of time (at least 1 order of magnitude above, yikes). It's from a library I'm still experimenting with. When I wrote this question, I hadn't `clock()` tested it, and thought it would be way faster. I'm gonna try to increase its performance first. If that's not enough, I'll use your implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @ATSlooking4things: not 30ms, 30 **microseconds!**.  This optimisation is useless in your case and only provided as an example of how to squeeze some cycles at the cost of readability and maintainability.

Comment: You're right. I misread it. Thanks for the heads up, and thanks for the solution nonetheless